# delete a key based on the refernmce of values in redis

Tags: redis, redis-cli, redisclient

Hi I have 100 key value pairs with different keys and same value in my redis now I want to delete all my key value pairs using value as reference how can I do it

Answer (score 0):

Approach will be same as how you'd do it in a Hash Map:

Iterate over ALL keys in the keyspace (use SCAN command)

Get value for each key

If value matches with what you are looking for: delete that key